# Tell or publish big file

Tags: akka

I have two nodes/machines/JVMs connected with Akka.
Each JVM has one different actor.
I am going to send large amount of messages from one actor to second.
Should I use tell() or create topic and subscribe/publish?

As I understand, tell is one-to-one communication and subscribe/publish is for one-to-many and many-to-many, however, as subscribe/publish also works for one-to-one (each actor may subscribe their own topic and publish to other, and thus communicate).
I do not know which one is better in this case.

What is difference in subscribe/publish and tell in one-to-one communication?
I am particularly interested in:
- performance (case 1: both on single node, case 2: on different nodes)
- design (with tell() I need to pass ActorRef first, while subscribe/publish allows to stay "anonymous")

I also should note, that in future I may need to stream big files between actors. By "big" I mean up to 4gb, but mostly thousands of kb/mb smaller files.

Comment: If you need to push big files, upload them to a blob store (e.g., S3) and sent a message telling the other actor the file is available.

Comment: Yes, this is default approach, but long story short, in this particular system this is not possible.

Comment: Pushing a 4gb message between two actors is still a really bad idea.

Comment: Even if this will happen over websocket? What is downside of this idea?